# Andengine SpriteBackground moves when camera is chasing player

Tags: android, background, camera, andengine, hud

My problem is that when the camera is moving to chase the player the background dosent change its position. It looks like the background would be a part of the HUD.

I have the player and the background in the same scene and I am using a bound camera.
My code for the camera to chase the player:

```
camera.setChaseEntity(player);
camera.setBounds(0, 0,2355,2785);
camera.setBoundsEnabled(true);
```

The code for adding the background to the scene:

```
SpriteBackground sp=new SpriteBackground(new Sprite(12,3,2355,2355,ResourcesManager.getInstance().background,vbom));
scene.setBackground( sp);
```

The chasing works with every other Entity. Bounds etc are working also
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I think for moving background you should use 'AutoParallaxBackground'  ..!!

Comment: just put your background like any other sprite and re,ember to atach it first so it is at the bottom layer